# How to use findCell when Smart Rendering is enabled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jscript, dhtmlx

I have a Grid where Smart Rendering is enabled, one of the operations on that Grid require that I locate several rows that have the same value in a particular column.

Columns are not necessarily sorted on that field, so I cannot assume the rows will be in the same sliding window of the buffer. During the `findCell` function, it throws an exception, when it crosses the buffer boundary. Is there a way to make this happen within the DHTMLX framework, or do I need to write special code for this?

Exception:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '_locator': object is null or undefined

```
_get_cell_value:function(a,b,c){return a._locator?(this._c_order&&(b=this._c_order[b]),a._locator.call(this,a.data,b)):‌​this.cells3(a,b)[c?c:"getValue"]()}
```

Comment: Can you show the exception being thrown?

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '_locator': object is null or undefined     \n    _get_cell_value:function(a,b,c){return a._locator?(this._c_order&&(b=this._c_order[b]),a._locator.call(this,a.data,b)):this.cells3(a,b)[c?c:"getValue"]()}

Comment: Its failing in dhtmlxgrid.js, I can see it has the first 50 rows in the buffer out of a total of 550, the loop variable is 50 when it fails, since it has not loaded the next set yet.

Comment: I meant update the actual question with the `exception`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what its worth, findCell appears to be incompatible with Smart Rendering, it doesn't automatically go down to the db to read in the next batch of rows to continue searching on the grid itself. I ended up writing my own rather lengthy Ajax/mvc search code to find the rows on disk and insert them on the grid.